# Repairing water-damaged paint (possibly drywall)?

Tags: painting, patching-drywall, water-damage

I have a first-floor wall that has some water damage in one of the corners. The cause was apparently a clogged gutter, which was spraying rain water directly onto the exterior of the wall. The clogged gutter is fixed but now I would like to repair the damaged interior paint.

My first idea was to simply remove the damaged paint, prime, and repaint with a color-matched paint color. However, I'm worried about whether more extensive work might be necessary, since I came upon some other threads that mentioned also replacing the drywall. (I'm a complete DIY novice, BTW.) Is this a case where I'd be fine with just repainting, or is there more to it than that?

Here's a picture of the damage. The house was built in 1994 but I believe the paint is relatively new...not entirely sure though. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it was indeed just recent & not an ongoing for years situation. Then, let it dry for a week or 2 & see how solid it is then. As long as it feels as solid as before & the rest of the walls, then definitely scrape off what bubbled, split & wrinkled paint you can so there are no lifting or flapping edges.

You'll want to fill those new low spots with Joint Compound or Spackle for a nothing ever happened end result. Lay that on in very-very thin coats just as thick as the paint you have surrounding the scraped areas. Dry-Sand with sandpaper to perfection & a lot of dust or Wet-Sand with a wet sponge for no dust. Let dry & do another Compound or Spackle coat, if needed & sand again.

Then, roller-on a Stain Blocking Primer & let that cure for 2-days, you shouldn't need a 2nd coat but do that if it's needed. And finally, roller-on your paint, 2-coats over the primer-ed areas & even do the rest of both walls to get everything uniform & to use up your paint...of course do this with the Primer too, prior to the paint, in order to use that up as well.